# Classification of algebraic groups of the types $^1\! A_{n-1}$ and $^2\! A_{n-1}$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a simply connected absolutely simple group
of one of the types $^1{\sf A}_{n-1}$ (inner) or $^2{\sf A}_{n-1}$
(outer) over a field $k$. All such groups are described on page 55
of Tits, Classification of algebraic semisimple groups,
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. 9 (Boulder), 1966, pp. 33-61.
The descriptions are as follows:

Type $^1{\sf A}_{n-1}$:
Special linear group ${\rm SL}_m(D)$, where $D$ is a central division algebra of degree $d$ over $k$, and $n=md$.

Type $^2{\sf A}_{n-1}$:
Special unitary group ${\rm SU}_m(D,h)$, where $D$ is a central division algebra of degree $d$
over a quadratic extension $K$ of $k$ with an involution of the second kind $\sigma$ such that
$k=\{x\in K\ |\ x^\sigma=x\}$,
$$h\colon D^m\times D^m\to D$$
is a nondegenerate hermitian form relative to $\sigma$, and $n=md$.

> **Question.** I am looking for a down-to-earth proof
> that all such groups are indeed of the form either ${\rm SL}_m(D)$ or  ${\rm SU}_m(D,h)$.
> (For me, the Book of Involutions is not down-to-earth.)

I know that my group becomes ${\rm SL}_n(\bar k)$ over an algebraic closure $\bar k$ of $k$.

Comment: Crossposted on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/455860/4149.